# KML more room in description for folder

Tags: kml

Does anyone know of a way to adjust the height of the description in a KML folder.

I have a structure that I (visually) want to look like this:

```
|[] kml_name                                 |
|    [] test/folder_name                     |
|        created: 2014-09-08 01:01:01.111111 |
|        description: foo...bar              |
|        [] Placemark_1                      |
|        [] Placemark_2                      |
|        ...                                 |
```

The KML, for example, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<name>kml_name.kml</name>
<Folder>
    <name>test_name</name>
    <description>created 2014-09-08 01:01:01.111111<br/>desc: foo...bar</description>
    <Placemark>
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/arrow.png</href></Icon>
                <heading>111.1111</heading>
                <color>ff008523</color>
                <scale>.6</scale>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
        </Style>
        <name>Placemark_1</name>
        <scale>0</scale>
        <color>ff008523</color>
        <description><b>duration:</b> 0.0408148765564<br/><b>time:</b> 2014-09-08 01:01:01.111112<br/><b>CNR:</b> 31.9<br/><b>BER:</b> 344</description>
        <Point><coordinates>-65.136866233,27.395845826,20.316</coordinates></Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <Style>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ffff0000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <name></name>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>-65.136866233,27.395845826,20.316,-65.136877726,27.395847788,20.077</coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
    ...
</Folder></Document>
</kml>
```

Is there a way to simply expand the `<description>` div (under `<Folder>`) in order to accommodate the `desc:` (because that is entirely cut off)?

Comment: Well, I half solved it by putting the description under the `<name>` instead of under the `<folder>`...

Comment: KML requires elements to be in a strict order. You need to reorder some of the elements to be a valid KML file. Validate your kml at http://kmlvalidator.com/